# C++ как располагаются методы?

Tags: c#, c++

1. К примеру есть файл .cpp, в нем есть метод, который не относится не к какому пространству `method(wchar_t ch) { .. }` куда этот метод по факту может относиться, если переводить его на c#, создание отдельного статического класса для таких групп методов?
2. Есть класс, он описан и тд, но я заметил в нем есть "вызова" методов, без всякого описания, то есть даже значения не передаются
   `static Class^ FromString(String ^ Source, keyType type, bool surround);`
   но эти методы описываются ниже класса не в каком либо namespace
   `namespace::class::method(String^ mng_str_ref, keyType type, bool surround) { .. }`
   как это работает например в c#? не могу сопоставить такую работу, похоже чуток на работу интерфейса, аналог что в классе описали такой методов, где то вне namespace его реализовали... Бред какой то.
   Помогите понять работу

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> К примеру есть файл .cpp, в нем есть метод, который не относится не к какому пространству method(wchar_t ch) { .. } куда этот метод по факту может относиться, если переводить его на c#, создание отдельного статического класса для таких групп методов?

В C# нет глобальных методов, так что да, метод должен быть объявлен как статический член класса. Однако, начиная с C# 6.0, можно использовать using static, чтобы обращаться к статическому методу без указания типа:

```
public static class MyClass
{    
    public static int Foo(int x,int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

---

```
using static ConsoleApplication1.MyClass;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Foo(1, 2));
    }       
}
```

> Есть класс, он описан и тд, но я заметил в нем есть "вызова" методов, без всякого описания, то есть даже значения не передаются ... но эти методы описываются ниже класса не в каком либо namespace ... как это работает например в c#?

В С++ разделение объявления и реализации используется, чтобы вынести в заголовочный файл только объявления методов. Это необходимо в связи с правилами языка касательно повторного определения функций (заголовочные файлы включаются во многих местах программы, а не-inline функция может быть определена только один раз). В C# нет необходимости разделять объявление и реализацию, так как нет понятия заголовочных файлов и вообще не используются forward declarations; язык устроен по другому. Реализации методов пишутся прямо в объявлении класса.

Если все же хочется объявить метод без реализации (например, заготовку на будущее), существуют [partial-методы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/partial-method):

```
public static partial class MyClass
{
    static partial void Bar();
}
```

---

```
public static partial class MyClass
{
    static partial void Bar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
```